# Pandas: Distribute a value over multiple timestamps when upsampling

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, resampling

I have a dataframe with timestamps in four-hour intervals that looks something like the following:

```
datetime              x_diff
2015-08-01 00:00:00   0
2015-08-01 04:00:00   100
2015-08-01 08:00:00   360
```

And I would like to upsample to get an hourly dataframe that looks like this:

```
datetime              x_diff
2015-08-01 00:00:00   0

2015-08-01 01:00:00   10
2015-08-01 02:00:00   20
2015-08-01 03:00:00   30

2015-08-01 04:00:00   40

2015-08-01 00:00:00   60
2015-08-01 00:00:00   80
2015-08-01 00:00:00   100

2015-08-01 08:00:00   120
```

Specifically, I want to linearly interpolate the `x_diff` values, but instead of drawing a line that passes through the values of `x_diff` in the original dataframe (0-100-360), I would like to **distribute** `x_diff` over the four previous hours in a linearly accumulating fashion (so that the sums over the previous 4 hours remain 0, 100, and 360).

Is there an easy command for doing this in Pandas, for example using resample or interpolate? The problem is that sometimes my interval size varies, e.g. to 2 hours or to 3 hours 50 minutes, so my intuition is that using a built-in Pandas method that works with datetime indices might be easier than writing a program of my own.

Thanks!

Comment: Been looking for something similar to this. So far no simple method found.

Comment: Yeah if I remember correctly I never had any luck :( If you find something helpful please do share!